# Send email with content based on gender but also use 2 different subjects based on gender

Tags: ampscript

The content of the email is based on gender.

The email is to be sent to 50% male and 50% female subscribers, but here is the bit I can't work out how to do. They also want to use 2 different subject lines based on gender and split the subject 50% across both female or male recipients, to work out which is the best subject line to use.

Can I do a 50% split for the subject using ampscript based on gender, and send the email using an AB test that is sent to say 50% male and 50% female subscribers, or is my logic out??

Answer (score 0):

You may have to break "male" into one send (DE/List) and "female" into another.

FURTHER CLARIFICATION:

Below are the 4 steps available to you when you A/B test in Marketing Cloud. If you focus on steps 1 and 2, then you'll see that your only choice is to A/B test by the sending List/Data Extension. Because of that, I believe your best choice in this question would be to separate your lists based on field value (can be done using a Filter for DE's) and using two separate sends.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86445)

Comment: @SebastianKessel How is it a bad answer? Looks like a genuine attempt at answering, and it's at least as high quality as the average answer on this site.

Comment: The “further clarification” wasn’t there when the post came up for review. You could’ve checked the timestamps before blasting me.

Comment: Thanks @Harley I ended doing as you suggested and creating 2 seperate address lists via filtering and then doing a A/B test for each list!